# Ошибка в коде, после работы скрипта не выводит значение после цикла

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Подскажите пожалуйста, где допустил ошибку в коде?
После срабатывания скрипта должно отобразится по идее значение 22.

```js
function Dismissal() {
  var arr = [[1, 3], [2, 22], 3, 4, 5, 6];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i][0] == 2) {
      return arr[i][1];
    }
    console.log(arr[i][1]);
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция возвращает значение как надо, если это функция, конечно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот это бессмысленно `console.log([i][1]);`. Должно быть `console.log(arr[i][1]);`

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, почему функция go вернула значение 3?

Comment: Точнее функция Diamissal

Comment: Это лог, функция вернула `22`